# Rails - tracking bookings on an event site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an events site using Rails. I need to create a system that monitors the number of bookings being taken to ensure an Event does not become over-subscribed. What is the most effective (DRY) way to do this? On my index page I have each event listed with a main image, event title and date. I also want to include a tracking message illustrating how many spaces are left e.g "50 spaces left - book now".

I've tried this code in my bookings controller but it doesn't work -

```
if @event.bookings.count >= @event.number_of_spaces
        flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
        redirect_to root_path


    end
```

Is there a more effective method to do this? I have a Booking MVC set up.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do this with a transaction, because there could be a case when two people try to book an event at the same time and so you end up with a greater number of bookings than number_of_spaces for an event.

In the controller:

```
Booking.transaction do
  @booking.save!
  @event.reload
  if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces
    flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
  end 
end
```

Or in the model:

```
def save_if_space_left
  Booking.transaction do
    save!
    event.reload
    if event.bookings.count > event.number_of_spaces
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
    else
      return true
    end
  end
  false
end

# So in the controller, you could do something like

if @booking.save_if_space_left
  # Successful
else 
  # Not successful
end
```

Comment: Does this go in the Booking model?

Comment: You could put it in the controller or the model. If you put it in the model you would have to put it into an instance method and instead of using `@booking` you could just call methods on self and instead of `@events` you would use `event`. I'll add an example in my answer to make it clear.

Comment: Many thanks. I've added my index.html.erb code with a further query regarding how I can express the ongoing booking.count - do you know how I can show this to show users how many spaces are left on the event?

Comment: you could create an instance method in your Event class: (using ; because its in one line) `def spaces_left; number_of_spaces - bookings.count; end`

Comment: And then just add <h3><%= event.spaces_left %></h3> to the code above?

Comment: you probably have it in an instance variable, so `@event`, but yeah

Comment: I've tried the code in the controller above and it doesn't appear to work. This was on a free event - I think I need to add more code to make it work for both free and paid events.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117225/discussion-between-jphager2-and-mike-whitehead).